# How can I finish transforming this JSON returned from a GraphQL query?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to transform a blob of nested JSON objects and arrays that are returned from my GraphQL query. By passing my data to a map() function and using spread operators I am am able to flatten my data most of the way, but I can't figure out how to get one level deeper to finish the job.

Data source:

```
// data from GraphQL
var sampledata = {
  data: {
    allNodeResource: {
      edges: [
        {
          node: {
            title: "Sample node 1",
            desc: {
              description: "Sample description"
            },
            relationships: {
              sin: [
                {
                  name: "Gluttony"
                },
                {
                  name: "Greed"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          node: {
            title: "Sample node 2",
            desc: {
              description: "Another sample description"
            },
            relationships: {
              sin: [
                {
                  name: "Lust"
                },
                {
                  name: "Wrath"
                },
                {
                  name: "Envy"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

Here is my initial attempt:

```
const flatten = arr =>
  arr.map(({ node: { title, relationships: sin, desc } }) => ({
    title,
    ...desc,
    ...sin,
  }));

const transformedJSON = flatten(sampledata.data.allNodeResource.edges);
```

That gets me most of the way, and returns this (as you can see `description` is now flat, and `sin` is almost flat, but not quite!):

```
[
  {
    "title": "Sample node 1",
    "description": "Sample description",
    "sin": [
      {
        "name": "Gluttony"
      },
      {
        "name": "Greed"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Sample node 2",
    "description": "Another sample description",
    "sin": [
      {
        "name": "Lust"
      },
      {
        "name": "Wrath"
      },
      {
        "name": "Envy"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My end goal is below, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get here:

```
[
  {
    "node": {
      "title": "Sample node 1",
      "description": "Sample description",
      "sin": [
        "Gluttony",
        "Greed"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "node": {
      "title": "Sample node 2",
      "description": "Another sample description",
      "sin": [
        "Lust",
        "Wrath",
        "Envy"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I feel like I'm a syntax error away from figuring this out, and have tried numerous combinations, such as trying to chain `sin` through another map() function, but I cannot seem to come up with the right technique (or maybe this is the wrong approach completely.)

Any tips on how to move this forward would be much appreciated...Tim

Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-jennings-h6smp?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaking your `flatten` function a bit, you can get the sin object to be flattened like this:

```js
const flatten = arr =>
  arr.map(({ node: { title, relationships, desc, ...rest } }) => ({
    title,
    sin: relationships.sin.map(sinObj => sinObj.name),
    ...desc,
    ...rest
  }));
```

Forked CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-glitter-f4xhn

You just need to pull out the name from the sin object. I also removed the destructuring of `relationships` into `sin` because that was causing you to end up with an object that would look like `sin: { sin: {}}`

Comment: thank you! I've been messing around with this all day and as I suspected I just could not figure out the right syntax, and was trying things such as `sin = > relationships...` instead of how you have it with `sin: relationships...`.

I'm a recovering PHP developer and still trying to wrap my head around some of this voodoo :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const newJSON = transformedJSON.map(json => {
  const changed = {...json};
  changed.sin = changed.sin.reduce((result, sin) => {
    return result.concat(sin.name);
  }, []);
  return changed;
});
```

Comment: thank you @Sjbrimley26! while I'm sure this would work I accepted the other answer because it used my original function and in a seemingly cleaner way (not concat etc.)